# Get sliced dataframe by giving two values

Tags: python, pandas

Given two values, how can I get all the value between those two values. Thank you

for example:

dataframe:

```
    Quarter GDP
0   1947q1  243.1
1   1947q2  246.3
2   1947q3  250.1
3   1947q4  260.3
4   1948q1  266.2
5   1948q2  272.9
6   1948q3  279.5
7   1948q4  280.7
8   1949q1  275.4
9   1949q2  271.7
10  1949q3  273.3
11  1949q4  271.0
12  1950q1  281.2
13  1950q2  290.7
14  1950q3  308.5
15  1950q4  320.3
16  1951q1  336.4
```

given 1947q3 and 1948q4, I need to get all the data between(inclusive) those two values

```
2   1947q3  250.1
3   1947q4  260.3
4   1948q1  266.2
5   1948q2  272.9
6   1948q3  279.5
7   1948q4  280.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the desired result

```
df[(df['Quarter'] >= '1947q3') & (df['Quarter'] <= '1948q4')]


    Quarter GDP
2   1947q3  250.1
3   1947q4  260.3
4   1948q1  266.2
5   1948q2  272.9
6   1948q3  279.5
7   1948q4  280.7
```

You can also use .between

```
df[df['Quarter'].between('1947q3', '1948q4', inclusive=True)]
```

Comment: `df.loc[]` is the recommended indexing syntax: [relevant pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

Answer (score 0):

put the data in dataframe.txt

```
f = open('dataframe.txt', 'r')
f_r = f.readline()
data = []
while f_r:
    infos = f_r.split(' ')
    infos = [info.strip() for info in infos if info]
    if len(infos) == 3:
        data.append((infos[1], infos[2]))
    f_r = f.readline()

def get_rangedata_by_quarter(quarter_s, quarter_b):
    """ quarter_s is the small one
        quarter_b is the big one
    """
    for info in data:
        quarter = info[0]
        if quarter >= quarter_s and quarter <= quarter_b:
            print quarter, info[1]


get_rangedata_by_quarter('1947q3', '1948q4')
```